# JFace: difference between ITreeContentProvider and ILazyTreeContentProvider

Tags: swt, jface

After reading [JavaDoc for ILazyTreeContentProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ILazyTreeContentProvider.html) and [Virtual Tables and Trees](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-Virtual/Virtual-in-SWT.html) I am a bit confused. Do they really mean that with a simple [ITreeContentProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ITreeContentProvider.html) *all* elements have to be loaded when the tree is created? I expected that `getChildren()` would only be called when expanding an element (and `hasChildren()` to be called to determine whether the plus sign should be shown). Or are they intended for the case where some elements have many children?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found [this](http://robshouse.net/feed-item/new-jface-32-m5-virtual-treeviewer-and-multiple-equal-elements):

> Support for SWT.VIRTUAL trees - see bug 112000. Note that all along, TreeViewer implemented lazy trees: the tree content provider's getChildren() method is only called when the user expands a node. The virtual tree viewer is helpful if there are lots of children per parent, or if it expensive to compute the information needed for each child.